# Embedding image into HTML in java?

Tags: java, html, image, embedded-resource

I have this code where I am trying to read an image from Url:

```
   public class question_insert {
public static String latex(String tex) throws IOException {

    String urltext = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl="+tex;

    URL url = new URL(urltext);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url
            .openStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process each line.
        System.out.println(inputLine.toString());

    }
    in.close();

    return inputLine;}
```

But what I am getting is unreadable code. The url gives only one image try this:

`http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=2+2%20\frac{3}{4}`

What should I do to embed the image into Html?

Comment: What do you mean by the unreadable code and image in HTML format? Data you get from the page is a PNG file - so save it.

Comment: I want to save the <img/> from the url in a String.

Comment: What do you expect your result to look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't know if that is what you want because it seems that nobody does. But if you want to get this output

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" 
src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=2+2%20\frac{3}{4}" />
```

you will have to use this code

```
public static String latex(String tex) {
    String url = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=" + tex;
    return "<img style=\"-webkit-user-select: none\" src=\"" + url + "\"/>";
}
```

Also you might have to escape some characters like `\` in the `tex` parameter.

Answer (score 12):

First of all it is not clear what you mean by *image in Html format* ? You could **Base64** encode its binary data, but is that what you really want?

How do you expect to output a PNG picture returned by your URL to a text console (that is System.out)?

Second, the way you're retrieving the image is not functional even if you were to store it on a disk as a PNG file, because Reader and its derivatives like BufferedReader are used to read character data. From [Reader API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html):

> Abstract class for reading character streams

You need to read binary (byte) data, so you need to stick with [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)

---

After some thinking I realized that embedding image into HTML is what you really want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String urltext = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=2+2%20\\frac{3}{4}";
    URL url = new URL(urltext);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[0];
    for(byte[] ba = new byte[bis.available()];
        bis.read(ba) != -1;) {
        byte[] baTmp = new byte[imageBytes.length + ba.length];
        System.arraycopy(imageBytes, 0, baTmp, 0, imageBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(ba, 0, baTmp, imageBytes.length, ba.length);
        imageBytes = baTmp;
    }
    System.out.println("<img src='data:image/png;base64," + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageBytes) + "'>");
}
```

The result is:

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,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'>
```

Isn't that great? Anything for you!

Comment: I am a newbie , I am just trying to read this from the url

<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&amp;chl=2+2%20\frac{3}{4}">

I am not displaying the image here.

Comment: @Navdroid But what do you expect to read? Text? You get an image - binary data. No wonder it's not readable.

Comment: All i want is to store <img /> in a string reading from the url

Comment: @Navdroid I don't understand. `<img />` is just a HTML tag. And what you get is **BINARY REPRESENTATION OF AN IMAGE**. Please explain exactly what you want to achieve. What do you want to store, where do you want to store it?

Answer (score 2):

To get your image, you should try to use ImageIO API like this

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(urltext);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sure that was a nice answer but how can you display this image using html?I meant in <img/> format

Comment: @Navdroid can you tell us in human terms what is the result that you're trying to achieve? What is <img/> format?

Comment: We are talking about generating HTML tag <img /> with embedded base64 source type. I'm not sure we can use the BufferedImage to do that, especially because we do not have access to internal byte[] here

Answer (score 0):

> http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=2+2%20\frac{3}{4}

Note that this URL is wrong. This shows `22 3/4` instead of the intended `2 + 2 3/4`.The request parameter containing special characters needs to be URL-encoded as follows.

> http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=2%2B2%20%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B4%7D

You can achieve this with `URLEncoder#encode()`.

```
String chl = "2+2 \\frac{3}{4}";
String url = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=" + URLEncoder.encode(chl, "UTF-8");
```

Back to your functional requirement:

> *What should I do to embed the image into Html?*

If your sole functional requirement is to display the image as available behind the mentioned URL by an HTML `<img>` element in a HTML/JSP page, then you need to use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:url>` tag to URL-encode request parameters containing special characters.

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:url var="url" value="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart">
    <c:param name="cht" value="tx" />
    <c:param name="chl" value="2+2 \\frac{3}{4}" />
</c:url>
```

Then you can just refer it as `${url}` (as declared in `var` attribute of `<c:url>`) in the `src` attribute of the HTML `<img>` element:

```html
<img src="${url}" />
```

Reading a binary image stream from an URL as a character stream and storing in a string as you initially attempted makes completely no utter sense. You also wouldn't open image files in notepad, for example.